# Using RxJS with filter(Boolean) for queries?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm reading through some code with the snippet:

```
search(query: string) {
  of(query).
  pipe(
    filter(Boolean), 
    debounceTime(300),
```

Is `filter(Boolean)` essentially the same thing as `filter(v=>!!v)`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, they are the same.

```
   console.log(typeof Boolean); // prints function
   console.log(Boolean.prototype.constructor("truthy")); // prints true
   console.log(Boolean === Boolean.prototype.constructor); // prints true
```

The `Boolean` global reference points to the constructor function which returns a boolean value from the first argument.

The constructor can be used to create a *boolean* wrapper object, but it is not the same as the primitive *true* value.

```
    console.log(new Boolean("truthy")); // prints an object.
    console.log(new Boolean("truthy").valueOf() === true); // prints true
    console.log((new Boolean("truthy")) === true); // prints false
    console.log(Boolean("truthy") === true); // prints true
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

Comment: I am a little confused. If `Boolean(false) === true` then `filter(Boolean)`is essentially NOT the same thing as `filter(v=>!!v)`!
Because `!!v`returns `false`if `v === false`.

Comment: `Boolean(false) === false`. Where did you get that `Boolean(false) === true`?

Answer (score 15):

They achieve the same result in that you don't get undefined values in your subscription.

The difference is that you lose Type Inference when using filter(Boolean)

```
const query = 'the query';

of(query).
  pipe(
     filter(Boolean)
  ).subscribe(val); // val here is of type 'Any'

of(query).
  pipe(
     filter(Boolean)
  ).subscribe((val: string)); // we can infer it back to string later

of(query).
   pipe(
      filter(v=> v!== undefined)
   ).subscribe(val); // val here is of type 'string'
```

Comment: Why do we lose type inference with filter(Boolean)? Is it related to TypeScript and/or RxJs? And is it documented by TypeScript and/or RxJs?

Comment: @Marcus it's related to TypeScript. The above isn't correct. The type will be inferred as `boolean` because you passed the constructor function as the callback, and the `filter` type infers typing from the callback's first argument type. Which is `Boolean(val: boolean)`. You can define the type yourself as `filter<string>(Boolean)` which tells the function what the observable type should be. Also, the above uses `String` when the original value was really `string`. The two types are not the same thing.

Comment: There used to be type issues. This is not true anymore with RxJS 7 - they fixed the type inference problem.

Comment: You can somehow "restore" the expected `boolean` type by casting the filter operator
`filter<boolean>(Boolean)`